# LESS Mixin with variable and content

Tags: css, less

So in sass, the mixin can do:

```
@mixin bp($point) {
  @if $point == papa-bear {
    @media (max-width: 1600px) { @content; }
  }
  @else if $point == mama-bear {
    @media (max-width: 1250px) { @content; }
  }
  @else if $point == baby-bear {
    @media (max-width: 600px)  { @content; }
  }
}
```

And can be used as:

```
.img {
  width: 33.33%;
  @include bp(baby-bear) {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Is there a similar way in LESS to dynamically generate the css? Especially passing a block of stylings like what the `@content` does here.

Comment: See [Passing Rulesets to Mixins](http://lesscss.org/features/#detached-rulesets-feature).

Answer (score 12):

Indeed you can use [Passing Rulesets to Mixins](http://lesscss.org/features/#detached-rulesets-feature) as already mentioned by @seven-phases-max.

For your break-points (bear types) in Less

You can use [pattern-matching](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature-pattern-matching):

```
.bp(papa-bear,@rules) {
@media (max-width: 1200px) {@rules();}
}
.bp(mama-bear,@rules) {
@media (max-width: 800px) {@rules();}
}
.bp(baby-bear,@rules) {
@media (max-width: 600px) {@rules();}
}

.img {
  width: 33.33%;
  .bp(baby-bear; { width: 100%;});
}
```

Or [mixin guards](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixin-guards-feature):

```
.bp2(@point,@rules) {
& when(@point = baby-bear) {
    @media (max-width: 600px) {@rules();}
}
& when(@point = mama-bear) {
    @media (max-width: 800px) {@rules();}
}
& when(@point = papa-bear) {
    @media (max-width: 1200px) {@rules();}
}
}

.img {
  width: 33.33%;
  .bp2(baby-bear; { width: 100%;});
}
```

In your example you can also write a single mixin:

```
.bp3(@point,@rules) {
  @query: ~"(max-width: @{point})";
  @media @query {@rules();}
}

.img {
  width: 33.33%;
  .bp3(600px; { width: 100%;});
}
```

Or when you have to reuse your bear types:

```
@baby-bear-max-width: 600px;
@mama-bear-max-width: 800px;
@mama-bear-max-width: 1200px;

.bp4(@bear,@rules) {
  @query: ~"(max-width: @{@{bear}-max-width})";
  @media @query {@rules();}
}

.img {
  width: 33.33%;
  .bp4(baby-bear; { width: 100%;});
}
```

Comment: @allejo Less tries to stay as close as possible to the declarative nature of CSS. For that reason guards are used in stead of more common if /else. Also Less uses lazy loading (and last declaration wins for variables), this unique feature make more suitable to use for frameworks i many case. An example can be found at http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-default-variables